# how to find probabilities that events will happed per hour

Tags: probability, descriptive-statistics

I have data set about creation of files during 24 h. Data covers period of 426 days. I sorted data based on hours of creation, data are presented in this table. numbers of files / day hours

```
0   1:00:00
0   2:00:00
0   3:00:00
1   4:00:00
0   5:00:00
0   6:00:00
6    7:00:00
179 8:00:00
261 9:00:00
153 10:00:00
134 11:00:00
107 12:00:00
111 13:00:00
116 14:00:00
66  15:00:00
31  16:00:00 
3   17:00:00
1   18:00:00
1   19:00:00
1   20:00:00
0   21:00:00
0   22:00:00
0   23:00:00
0   0:00:00
```

just simple explanation from 08 AM - 09 AM there are 261 files. I did not take in a consideration if this is result of day with one created file or more I just counted numbers of files that are created in this period. I want to find probability for every hours. Based on numbers of files biggest probability for creation files during day is from 08 - 09 AM, but I do not know how to calculate this.

Comment: you have sum every days of the same hour ?

Comment: Thats right, this is sum of the same hours, for every day.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear, what exactly your goal is, but I will give it a shot anyway.

The estimation of probabilities is not possible without further assumptions. In general, these can be tested, but that would require a different structure of the data.

First, is the creation of files independent? I.e. if N files have been created within a given time interval, is the probability for the next interval (of the same length) the same or different? I.e. can you tell anything about the probability by looking at some kind of history or not.

If you cannot assume independence, we really cannot do much here, as we do not know the history and cannot derive it from this dataset. In that case you would have to get a dataset that describes the events for each day and each hour. Then you could derive some kind of autoregressive model or Fourier regression (out of scope for this question).

If you can assume independence, then you have a [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), for which the probabilities can easily be estimated (except for the hours with 0 events, which have insufficient data for estimating a Poisson distribution). The Poisson distribution has a single parameter $\lambda$, which is best estimated by the mean. Since you did not give any indication, how many days you averaged, it is however not possible to calculate this. For sake of example, I will just assume your data comes from 10 days of data collection. In that case, your probability for files being created between 8:00 and 9:00 is $P(k) = e^{-261/10}\frac{(261/10)^k}{k!}$, e.g. the probability of 26 files being created in this interval would be $e^{-26.1}\frac{26.1^{26}}{26!}=0.0779737$. If you want to have the probability of at least one file being created you can do this by using the usual equalities for probabilies.

Answer (score 0):

You summed the number of file created on the same hour for each day.

It's really hard to work like that, you lose a lot of information, if you can have the same data but on the 426 days, you will have a really better idea of what is going on. And you would be able to makes probabilities. (one file created every  days the same hour, and only one day with 426 files created the same hour is not the same, but the result will be 426 on this hour..).

The best way would be something between rare event and temporal series.

---

By the way, if you divide the data by the 426, you obtain this graph : [image]

This can be enough for you. 
If you want to make hypotheses, it's up to you, (like smoothing the serie or things like that) but I won't because we don't have enough information.

Comment: I do have data for every day per hour i summarized I will present here data for files created from 06:00 - 07:00 h AM since there are just 6 of them.

Comment: I do have data for every day per hour and i summarized them. I will present here data for files created from 06:00 - 07:00 h AM since there are just 6 of them.
date - time - size (MB)
11.4.2014 - 6:59:00-    9,062
25.4.2014- 6:15:00- 6,129 
16.9.2014- 6:31:00- 6,830 
30.9.2014- 6:37:00- 7,409 
30.9.2014- 6:38:00- 5,581
22.6.2015- 6:55:00- 6,298

If I find probability using sum of files from certain hour / total number of files and then divide that with total number of days. I am trying to determine probability that user will create file in time from 06 - 07 during period of 426 days.